# How to trigger even on dynamic element?

Tags: jquery

I have some radio buttons that created by ajax request using something like this:

```
document.getElementById("clientresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

The radio buttons are output from another file.
How can I use $('input:radio').change() to trigger events on selecting these radio buttons?

Comment: When triggering events, it does'nt really matter if they are dynamic as long the elements exists when you are targeting them, you can't trigger something on something that does not exist.

Comment: Kyle, I think you need to read about how to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to delegate event handling to an ancestor element. Once you have mastered this technique, you will have the means of giving event-driven behaviour to current *and future* elements, without needing to attach further event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked and answered many many times but here you go

For `on()` to work on events that yet don't exist, it needs binding to one that does that will be a parent of those future elements.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function(){
    // whatever you want to happen
});
```

`document` is  catch-all but I believe it's faster to bind to something with fewer nodes to search (if that's the right terminology) e.g.

```
<div id="clientresult">
    <!-- inputs will be created in here -->
</div>

$('#clientresult').on('change', 'input:radio', function(){
    // whatever you want to happen
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have found some other questions but they tend to focus more on other issues. Your explanation is clear enough to understand how the "binding" works.