# Clicking on a dynamically created link not recognizing click event

Tags: php, jquery

When you click on a folder a button/link is prepended to the nav section but when i click on the added button it will not work. It does not recognize my click event for some reason..?

quick video of what i am dealing with. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsW1uLbRd9w

I am clueless on why it is not working ahhhh
Any help would be awesome, thanks.
If you need more code i can send it if needed.

```
    <script>
      $(function () {
        // When folder is clicked open it
        $('button.<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>').bind('click', function() { 
            $('.open.<?php echo $row->folderName;?>').show();
              // if folder is open then Prepend homebtn button to nav
              var k = $('.open').css('display');
              if(k == 'block') {
                $('.nav').prepend('<a class="gohome">HELLO</a>');
              }
        });
            $('.gohome').live('click', function() {
                $('.open.<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>').hide();
              });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: `.live()` and `.bind()`? When did you last update jQuery? `.bind()` is okay, it works (it's `.on()` now), but `.live()` is not recommended.

Comment: i didn't think .live worked anymore but i am desperate, any other suggestions? what should i use instead of .bind?

Comment: thanks, i'll try that. dont think that is the problem though.

Comment: You should use the latest jQuery and add a click event handler to the parent of the `button` elements using `.on()`. Maybe something like this: `parentElement.on('click', 'button.the_button_class', handler);`

Comment: Thanks, what should i use instead of .live?

Comment: You should use .on() for future elements. And I mean the syntax for future events, not just use .on() instead of .live() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298929/how-to-trigger-even-on-dynamic-element  `$(document).on('click', '.gohome', function...`

Comment: Here is a quick video of my project, as you can see the home button does not work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsW1uLbRd9w

Comment: A video showing the problem will not help. Read my answer. If it doesn't make sense search Google for binding future events using jQuery on.

Comment: Delegation is the key :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind to future elements you need to bind the event to a parent that exists at the time that the procedure is executed. As your link as being added to `.nav`, that's what we can use. I am assuming `.nav.` exists when this code is run. If not, use `$(document).on('click'...`

```
  $('.nav').on('click', '.gohome', function() {
      $('.open.<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help and understanding. it ended up working with your code:)